# Every integer $α>2$ can be expressed as $2a+3b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am confused about a homework problem I have, and don't really know where to begin. I need to prove this. Any idea of where I can start. I am not necessarily looking for a solution, but a place to begin. The statement is that

Show that every integer $α > 2$ can be written in the form $α = 2a + 3b$ where $a$ and $b$ are
nonnegative integers.

Comment: Hint;  if $n$ can be so expressed then so can $n+2$ (why?)

Comment: can you write more clearly ?

Comment: What is unclear about what I wrote?  I am suggesting that you start by proving the (simple) claim I provided.  Then show that $n=3,4$, say, are all expressible in the form you want.  Side note:  there is no reason to exclude $\alpha =2 $

Comment: @lulu Shouldn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: "Shouldn't you post this as an answer? " Good god, no!

Comment: @Manan  For posts like this, that show no effort at all, a quick sketch is the furthest I will go.  Arguably, that's already too far.

Comment: As an aside, the generalized problem is commonly referred to in the literature as the [Frobenius Coin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) and is worth checking out after you've familiarized yourself more with proof techniques and other elementary number theory topics like greatest common divisor and Bezout's identity.  This particular example though should require very little effort once you understand lulu's hint.

Comment: Hint  $3 = 2+1$ so $2a + 3b = 2a + 2b + b = 2(a+b) + b$.  Hint 2: Consider even and odd cases.

Comment: Couple more hints:  If $m = j + k$ and $j = 2a+3b$ and $k=2c+3d$ than $m = 2(a+c) + 3(b+d)$.   And if $m= 2a+3b$ then $m + 2 = 2(a+1) + 3b$ and $m+3 = 2a + 3(b+1)$  and... well, connect the dots.

Comment: @lulu I guess the comments are intended for suggestions to improve the question or seek clarification on what's being asked; yours seem to be a complete answer since the OP only sought a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For even $\alpha$ take $b=0$; what then is $a$? For odd $\alpha$ take $b=1$; what then is $a$?